# Explain Windows 10 Virtual Account (service acc) permissions

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions, services, privileges

I am trying to run a PHP-CGI in a low-privilege Virtual Account (Win10 Pro).

How is this ***([See screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZshf.png))*** possible?

I am running a PHP-CGI service, under a (Virtual) Account *NT Service\PHP*. The effective permissions of that user in C:\ are all **forbidden**. 
However, when running the MKDIR command in a PHP shell-script (that is being ran via PHP-CGI.exe by the *NT Service\PHP* user) I **can** create a directory in C:\ .... Is this a ridiculous security/permissions flaw or what am I missing here?

[Screenshot #2 (running MKDIR)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoDtY.png)

Running "whoami" in the PHP-Shell gives: *nt service\php*

Bonus sidequestion: How can I create a Group of Virtual Accounts (service accounts), to easily set filesystem-permissions for multiple services at once?

Comment: I see, the PHP user is part of Authorized Users group.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found out what caused this. The 'NT Service\PHP' user is part of the group 'Authenticated Users'.

For the bonusquestion: open lusrmgr.msc , create a group, add the appropiate NT Service\names accounts to the group.